# Marking SMS as read on Android not working

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to mark a message as read on a Samsung Galaxy S6 and it is not working. I have following tutorials online. My code is below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, "_id=" + id, null, null);
try {
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read", true);
        context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, "_id=?", new String[] { id });
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Mark Read", "Error in Read: " + e.toString());
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong? I pass in a `id` to this method and the message is always marked as unread. How is it that other SMS applications can mark as read and I cannot?

Comment: Are you sure that the `id` is correct?  If `getCount()` returns 0, nothing will ever be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot mark SMS messages as read if you are NOT the default SMS client. Lame!

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least explain why? This was a valid question as it is not known to many that only default applications can modify the content.